# Is there a way to add action to all the created nodes except one node in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, enumeration

I want to add an action for all nodes on the scene except one or two nodes.

Or, I would like to find a way to access to all nodes with a different way of using the "name" method.

This not the complete game but I do not want to use the "name" method because every square has different name.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
var Score = 0

class GameScene: SKScene {

let SquareSide = 100
var touchedNode = SKNode()
var touchLocation = CGPoint()
let ScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
let squareNumber = 0

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
CreatSquares()
}

func CreatSquares(){

let square = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x:        Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))), y:  Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.height))), width: SquareSide, height: SquareSide))

if Score <= 10{
square.fillColor = UIColor.orange}
else{
square.fillColor = UIColor.blue
        }
square.physicsBody =        SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: square.frame.width, height: square.frame.height), center: CGPoint(x: square.position.x, y: square.position.y))

square.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

square.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
square.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
square.name = "square\(number)"

number++
self.addChild(square)

    }


}
func CreatScoreLabel(){
let ScoreLabel = SKLabelNode()

ScoreLabel.text = "Your Score is:\(Score)"

ScoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height - 50)

ScoreLabel.color = UIColor.white
    self.addChild(ScoreLabel)

}

func updatScore(){
ScoreLabel.text = "Your Score is:\(Score)"

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches:     Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
for touch in touches {
touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
touchedNode = self.atPoint(touchLocation)
if touchedNode.name == "square"{
Score += 1
touchedNode.removeFromParent()
            }


    }

    }
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
updatScore()
}
```

Comment: I find that your question is unclear, can you please explain a but more so I can help?

Comment: I want to add action for all the created nodes on the scene except one node (like the LabelNode for example)

Comment: But right now in my code i ave only one node to that i do not want to add the action for it but when i want to complete my game there more than one node. Do not want to add the action for them.

Comment: Like anything make the function of this but without using nodes' name :self.enumerateChildNodesWithName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by [Confused](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41115256/1894067) I think you forgot the real power of [enumerateChildNodes(withName:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483024-enumeratechildnodes)

Indeed, about the name:

> The name to search for. This may be either the literal name of the
>   node or a customized search string. See [Searching the Node Tree](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode#1654468).

This means that you also could do:

```
self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//square*") { node, _ in
   // node is equal to each child where the name start with "square"
   // in other words, here you can see square0, square1, square2, square3 etc...
   if node.name == "square3" {
      // do whatever you want with square3
   }
}
```

**`//`** specifies that the search should begin at the root node and be performed recursively across the entire node tree. Otherwise, it performs a recursive search from its current position.

**`*`** means that the search matches zero or more characters.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to add all the nodes you want to add the actions to into an array, then iterate over that array, adding actions when you want/need.

This has a memory hit if your objects are huge and complex, but is the most organised and rapid way to do it without using `.name`.

And is far faster and easier than messing around through your node hierarchy with `enumerateChildNodes...` etc